# How to split on multiple character pattern in js?

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have this string:

```
string = 'addition and subtraction 1';
```

I want to split this string on spaces except when there's a number after a space. So like this:

```
['addition','and','subtraction 1']
```

How do I do this?

Comment: `string.split(/ (?!\d)/g)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A negative lookahead in your split regex accomplishes this

```js
console.log('addition and subtraction 1'.split(/ (?!\d)/g));
```

Answer (score 2):

See This:

```
 var str="addition and subtraction 1";
    var splitstr=str.split(/ (?!\d)/g);
    console.log(splitstr)
```

Answer (score 1):

**try this :**

```
string = "addition and subtraction 1".split(/ (?!\d)/g));
```

**output:**

```
["addition", "and", "subtraction 1"]
```